# Angular 10 - Problem with navigation between child routes of different modules

Tags: angular

In my general routes configuration file I have the following:

```
{
path: `users`,   
loadChildren: () => import('./@pages/users/users.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
}
```

In the module paths configuration file: UserModule, I have the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:  ``, 
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "detail",
        component: DetailUserComponent
      }
    ]
  } 
];
```

From the html template of the UserComponent component I have the following link that should navigate to DetailUserComponent:

```
this.router.navigate(['users/detail'], { queryParams: { name: this.data.name, surname: this.data.surname }});
```

But it does not navigate to the DetailUserComponent component template it stays in UserComponent, even though the address in the navigation bar is correct.

What could be failing ?, Thank you.

Comment: is there any error appearing in the console ?

Comment: No, the console does not show any errors